# Brewing tea with deionized water

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solubility, ions, safety

I am wondering what efect brewing tea (let us assume for the sake of simplicity it is green tea, brewed at about 80 °C) in deionized water might have on the product.

- Will the lack of ions in the water increase or decrease the solubility of alcaloids from the tea leaves. Will the effect be different for alkaloids in salt and alcaloids in amine form?
- Will drinking moderate amounts of such tea (0.5–1 l per day) detrimentally affect one's electrolyte metabolism? I am guessing maybe it does not matter, since the tea fills the water with electrolytes anyway – but will these electrolytes be significally different from what you would get in tap/mineral water? and if so, will it matter?

Comment: I'd say there'd be just less electrolytes in it than a normal cup of tea. As for if it's healthy or not there's too many variables and factors that could lead to how it would effect your health  in particular that I wouldn't want to make an assumption as I don't know you. Sorry I don't know if it would be bad or not for you.

Comment: In lower Michigan there have been places where the water has $\ce{H2S}$ in the tap water. Using bottled or deionized water for tea in those places would make the tea drinkable. So unless you can taste a difference the more expensive water is pointless.

Comment: You might contemplate the difference between deionized and distilled water. Distilled water is corrosive because it really wants solutes in it. Deionized has merely exchanged certain ions for other ions. Now, I once worked in a lab where we always made coffee with distilled water, and it tasted just fine and I'm still alive.

Comment: And to add anecdotic evidence to @JonCuster’s: Yes, I was an intern in a group that used a samowar; the tea concentrate was brewed with deionised water while it was diluted with normal hot water. They did it for a reason which I can’t remember, but probably had something to do with easier cleaning.